# How to show 2 colors in layer list with responsive UI in different screen sizes

Tags: android, responsive-design, height, splash-screen, layer-list

I need to show a splash screen with 2 colors. 1 of the color hight requires 40% and another one requires 60%.
UI is not responsive for different screens when I provide height in dp.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:height="290dp" android:gravity="fill_horizontal|top">
        <color android:color="#00549F"/>
    </item>
     <item android:height="560dp" android:gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white"/>
     </item>
    <item android:bottom="80dp">
        <bitmap
          android:src="@drawable/Image_null"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

I Tried below code with layout.But it's not working.Showing errors at weightSum

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/white" android:weightSum="2">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="#00549F"/>
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1.2">
            <ImageView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/Image_null"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
    }

   
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
        StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think its possible since it takes dimension not percentage . better have two views in layout with weight .

Comment: I tried with layout and used weightSum.It's showing errors for weightSum and weight's.
@ADM My layout code also upadated.Please check once

Answer (score 0):

Divide screen in two parts and set the background to each part .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="#00549F" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to start activity android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/splash_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b0082'

@ADM getting this error

Answer (score 0):

The values for left, top, right and bottom are measured from their respective edge.

So left=0dp, top=0dp, bottom=0dp & right=50dp will give you a rectangle that is (match_parent - 50dp) wide and not 50dp wide. Therefore larger values for "right" will actually give you a smaller rectangle.

The same would apply to the other value, but these would behave as expected in most cases, its just "right" that might cause confusion.

Either you use px instead of dp or multiply all dimensions by 10.

Divide screen in two parts:-

android:layout_weight=5
android:layout_weight=5

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` and divide with two different child views and assign them weight. Use below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#00549F" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to start activity android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/splash_screen.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b0082' @Sniffer getting this error

Comment: did you copy and paste this code as it is... show your activity code

Comment: Yes...I'm implementing this in splash screen.The error is getting that splash screen is not found

Comment: show your splash screen code. Not xml code

Comment: Provided above the screenshot. Please check once.

Comment: Provide the Java code. If possible  remove this line from XML code `android:src="@drawable/Image_null"`

Comment: Java code updated above.Please check once

Comment: Did you forget to set your layout  `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`

Comment: No...I'm using this splash screen in Xamarin.Android Project.
So I didn't added that line

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776598/5978440)

Comment: Checked. There is no use with that answer.